# Why is a question requesting to support answer with official documentation an off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have always felt that what is on or off topic for Stackoverflow is quite dicey considering that we see tons of questions everyday which apparently are well accepted but one odd question which might follow the same footstep could be well shot down by the community. In most cases it seemed to me, it more because of crowd effect, timing among others.

In one particular case, a question that was asked, started gathering close votes and eventually was closed down [What are the equivalent directives for forcing a function inline for various compilers? [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524860/what-are-the-equivalent-directives-for-forcing-a-function-inline-for-various-com)

Now, till to date, I had asked few questions in this site, that explicitly requested to provide relevant references with the answers. Official Documentation of tools, compilers, language references are often considered a good reference to support an answer. In the above case, when I enquired

> Why is this off-topic? And can you please elaborate why you think this
>   asks for recommendation of book/tool or software library?

I received a reply that seemed to be supported by other community members

> @Abhijit Can any one provide me a link to the documentation Close
>   reason: other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow That
>   is probably why

So, when a question explicitly requests to support an answer/provide authentic references with official documentation should be an off-topic? Why is it so?

Let me re-quote the close reason and highlight the relevant portion of it

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow ***as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam***."

So my understanding was, the reason to close a question as off-topic was iff it requested for some references, resources, recommendation that results in varied opinions as been clearly mentioned in the close reason.

Saying that, how would an official documentation **attract opinionated answers and spam**?

Comment: Not the best close reason. To me, the problem with your question is that it is a "list question". There's dozens of C++ compilers out there. Since what you're asking isn't covered by the standard, each of them can do it differently (or not at all). Not a good fit for SO.

Comment: @Mat: Yes I agree, but shouldn't it be a good reference for future developers? We do accept questions that are vendor specific, and this question was a real life scenario where you had to create a solution that is portable across multiple environments. A real programming question should be on-topic right?

Comment: "List questions" aren't. Wikipedia's better at that sort of thing.